# Should I have separate Angular components for buttons, even if they are reused? best practice question

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am writing a to-do list application, and I'd like to display active, completed and deleted tasks.

Active tasks are the tasks that I can delete or complete, completed tasks are tasks that I can delete, and deleted tasks is just a graveyard.

Every task can have details, so I think I should have a `task-display.component` which is responsible for displaying clickable tasks.

As for the component that displays active tasks, I want to have my `task-display` + two buttons: delete and complete.

As for the component that displays completed tasks I don't know, since I can certainly reuse my `task-display` component, but I'm not sure whether I want to have a delete button as a separate component. If I decide to do so, it seems like too much of a hassle for just one button. If I decide against it, however, I'll have duplicating code.

What would the best solution be?

Comment: Take a look at Angular best practices : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/best-practices-for-a-clean-and-performant-angular-application-288e7b39eb6f 
task 12 could be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As one would say: YAGNI.

Don't bother splitting this buttons. You don't know how it will evolve or if you'll need to reuse the component. You'll ask yourself how to do it when you'll actually encounter this situation.

And when it will happen i'm pretty sur it will be far from what you've expected ^^